# Devise/OmniAuth/Twitter - OAuth::Unauthorized (401)

Tags: twitter, devise, omniauth

I'm trying to set up a Twitter login using Devise/OmniAuth, following the latest RailsCast for this.  I've registered the Twitter developer app, using the callback url of: `myiphere:port/users/auth/twitter`.

I've followed everything to the T on the RailsCast, but each time I click the `Sign In With Twitter` link, I immediately get `OAuth::Unauthorized 401 Unauthorized on the myiphere:port/users/auth/twitter page`.

I think I've defined the key correctly using `export TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY=MYKEYINSERTEDHERE export TWITTWR_CONSUMER_SECRET=MYSECRETINSERTEDHERE rails server`.  I've tried most every solution I can find on the internet, all to no avail.  Almost all of the answers are for returning back to their site once logged in, I can't get to any kind of Twitter screen, just the 401 error on the `/users/auth/twitter` page.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I had this same issue; in my case, I had the API keys set up correctly, but had not set a callback URL in the Twitter setup at https://dev.twitter.com/apps/, under the "Settings" tab.

Oddly, it doesn't appear that the callback URL needs to point anywhere useful; Twitter apparently just uses its existence as a signal of some sort.

The debugging information provided by omniauth-twitter leaves something to be desired.

Answer (score 3):

I got it to work by removing the brackets and ENV from the initializer DEVISE.RB:

```
config.omniauth :twitter, "APP_ID", "APP_SECRET"
```

my callback specified in DEV Twitter settings:

```
http://www.mysite.com/users/auth/twitter/callback
```

In routes.rb

```
devise_for :users, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}
```

My LogIn link:

```
<%= link_to "Log in with Twitter", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter) %>
```

Comment: You saved me hours of frustration. I too was setting my initializer using ENV vars, and have a scope as well. For whatever reason, with some users I was getting a 401 upon authentication. After hard-coding the values it now seems to work for everyone. A) Thanks B) WHAT?!

Answer (score 2):

Answering my own question here, it seems that I just needed to add the actual keys in place of `TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY` and `TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET`, and not the way I'd originally tried to add them.  I also removed the `ENV[]` from each one, I think that may of helped.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the figaro gem in order to use environmental variables like in the video. The link will walk you through how to set them up.

http://railsapps.github.io/rails-environment-variables.html

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was that "Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter" wasn't checked (Under app page > settings tab)